# C++ with pthread executing a member function

Tags: c++, pthreads

I want to write a little test program with pthreads in c++, i have no experience with pthreads but what i've read so far is that there are problems because pthreads are a C construct.

My code is the following:

```
class A{
       public:
            int main();
            void* do_work();
            static void* helper_do_work(void*);
};

void * IMagFieldSvc::do_work(){
}

void* IMagFieldSvc::helper_do_work(void* context)
{
          return ((IMagFieldSvc*)context)->do_work();
}
int A::main(){
…
          pthread_create(&thread, &attr, &helper_do_work, &svc);
          pthread_join(thread, NULL);
}
```

but compiling it with:

g++ -pthread test.cxx

returns

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to`main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

i tried adding

```
extern "C" void* helper_do_work(void*);
```

whatever this does, but the error is the same

halp pleeze?

dunno if i should open a separate question for this:
also, in do_work i want to access and change member variables, the whole aim of the exercise was to find out how i can access and change member variables making them thread local with __thread. these member variables are of a self defined type with their own constructors and destructors, i don't know why that would make a difference, but apparently it does...

Comment: Well, for starters, the error is saying that you have no `main()` function. You seem to have an `A::main()`, but not a global `main()`...

Comment: Note, that this has absolutely nothing to do with threads!

Comment: The `extern "C"` is not needed. Normal static member like you have in the initial code is just fine. The `main`, however, isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `main` cannot be a member function, it must be defined in a global namespace.

Define it like this:

```
int main()
{
// ...
}
```